# Создается новая сессия при каждом запросе

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express

Я стараюсь реализовать вход (не JWT, не passport.js и т.д.)(просто вход то есть, пост запрос на сервер, проверка с базой данных есть ли пользователь, если да то вошел, если нет то заново). Проблема такова, сессии создаются так, проверка на валидность данных, если все ок тогда мы в сессию записываем рандомно сгенерированный ключ `req.session['login'] = abc123(100)` и так же записываем ник пользователя `req.session['user'] = indata.login`, и возвращаем `true`, если же данные не подтвердились тогда мы возвращаем `false`, если сессия уже существует возвращаем `log_true`.

Моя проблема в том что, при каждом новом запросе на сервер какой бы он не был post/get все равно создается новая сессия. Запрос посылаю на сервер с VUE-cli (собираю полный проект).
p.s. Не работает именно через VUE, если сделать запрос прямо на сервер тогда все работает норм.

### настройки сессии

```
app.use(
    session({
        secret: 'dfsalmlkdsmf',
        store: new redisStorage({
            client: client
        }),
        proxy: true,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    })
);
```

### обработчик входа

```
app.post('/login_s', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    login = req.body.login;
    password = req.body.password;
    let indata = {
        login: login, 
        password: password
    };  
    if (req.session["user"] != abc_login_fds) {
        getdata('check_log', indata).then(function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
                req.session['user'] = indata.login;
                req.session['login'] = abc123(100);
                res.send(true)
            } else {
                res.send(false)
            };            
        });
    } else {
        res.send('log_true')
    };
});
```

### запрос на сервер из vue

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        data: {
          login: this.loginin,
          password: this.passwordin
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_s'
      })
        .then(response => {
          if (String(response.data) === 'log_true') {
            console.log(312)
            location.href = '/'
          } if (String(response.data.user) === this.loginin) {
            document.cookie = 'sid_user=' + response.data.login
            console.log(document.cookie)
          }
        })
```

Comment: А где входе проверяется, что у пользователя есть уже сессия, такое впечатление, что она каждый раз заново создается

Comment: Так и есть. Она каждый раз заново создается. Каждый раз Id сессии меняется